# Is it possible to dynamically and accurately calculate variable compounding percentage using native excel functions?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find out if it is possible using native excel function to create a dynamic calculation, that takes initial value then adds compounded percentage over the period that at which this percentage is active all the way to the end of the period.

Here is sample of the calculations that I currenly do manually.

[image]

I can do calculation manually without any issues, the problem is that all my values for different rate and dates are static and cannot be easily changed, lets say I want to add extra periods and extra dates, this would mean that I will have to restructure formula to account for each percentage and period that I add to the percentage table. If I have to use VBA the calculations are not as accurate because of the vba variable type constraints.

So is it possible to create a formula that would automatically read the rate table, lookup necesary values regardless of amount of rows in the rate table and calculate compounding variable rate from start date => end date

- 1st thing I need to find is initial rate for start date (1%) as
  04/May/12 falls in period between 6/Apr/11 => 5/Sep/12.
- 2nd thing I need to find is number of days between start date (4/May/12) and date (5/Sep/12) when start rate changes 1% => 2%
- 3rd if the end date is outside the range of the "rate table" the last rate of 2% should be used
- Result compounds variable rate all the way to from start date (04/May/12) to the end date (05/Feb/14) with initial value 1000.

Comment: Have you tried vlookup()?

Comment: I do understand how vlookup works but it does not help with dynamic table stracture that can change to different amount of rates and periods. In the example above I have simple table, which has only two rows and two periods, what if I have 100 periods with different rates, and I have to chose any date as start date and be able to calculate compounding rate to the end date of my choosing,  creating such formula becomes problematic.

Comment: What dynamic table?

Comment: I may change rate table to lets say

1% => 04/04/12

2% => 04/04/13

3% => 04/04/14

4% => 04/04/15

the formula will have to adjust to each new period added to the table

Comment: vlookup() will use the values in the table and if they get updated then it uses what is there.

Comment: the start date may not match with the rates date

Comment: "I have to remember?" you are the one asking the question...

Comment: it is just a figure of speach, no harm meant